# Capturar o IP e Nome da maquina local

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

Preciso pegar o ip e nome da maquina local do cliente no caso o usuário que estará acessando o meu sistema.

Meu sistema está hospedado na redehost o sistema e banco de dados. Os comandos que eu usei até agora eu pego o nome do servidor e ip do servidor, mas eu preciso saber que o usuário esta acessando o sistema de dentro do escritório nosso.

Base de dados MYSQL, já usei vários comandos, mas já apaguei vou colocar os dois últimos que estou usando abaixo:

```
string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_host"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
        String ecn = System.Environment.MachineName;                                  
        string vNomeMaquina = computer_name[0].ToString();


    string Ip;

        System.Net.IPHostEntry v_ipMaquina = System.Net.Dns.Resolve(vNomeMaquina);
        System.Net.IPAddress[] address = v_ipMaquina.AddressList;
        for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++) //ciclo q escreve o ip
            Ip = (Ip + address[i]);
```

Comment: Qualquer linguagem ?

Comment: asp.net nao é linguagem. É C#?

Comment: infome qual base de dados está usando, e ali você fala C# asp.net, mas é preciso saber mais. Poderia ser webforms, pode ser mvc ou ainda asp.net core. Se possível, coloque um trecho do seu código, onde gostaria de pegar esses dados

Comment: Usei agora os seguentes comandos: Para o nome host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_host"]).HostName; e deu este resultado = b39f88fe.virtua.com.br

Comment: e usei o comando, public static string GetPublicIP()  {
        string url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org";
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        string[] a = response.Split(':');
        string a2 = a[1].Substring(1);
        string[] a3 = a2.Split('<');
        string a4 = a3[0];
        return a4;
    }

Comment: ip = GetPublicIP(); e o resultado é este = 187.84.230.84

Answer (score 1):

Você pode acessar o IP do usuário através do `HttpContext` com o seguinte código:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Agora o nome da maquina local através do C# não é possivel por questões de segurança.

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo, este comando pega o IP do provedor testei aqui agora e pegou do meu provedor da Net.

Comment: Ahh você quer o IP local também?

Comment: Isso Leandro o IP local e se possível o nome da maquina local também.

Comment: Ok João, vou ver se consigo achar uma solução para seu caso.